# How To Display A Related List Of Custom Object

Tags: community, custom-object, related-list

I've created a custom object and I would like to know how to display a related list for that object?
Please have a look at the screenshot.
[image]

Please advise how to display a related list for Cases custom object.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: you have to create a lookup or masterdetail relationship between case custom object and the object you want to see as related list. Then you can see the object as related list.  You can configure this from the edit page layout, and select related list on the left panel then drag and drop to view.

Comment: Not related to your question but I would advise not using the same name as a standard object for your custom object.  It can get really confusing at times (I know from experience).  If you can I would advise changing the name at least slightly to make it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Related List is on  the page layouts of any object that is either the Master in a Master Detail relationship or the parent in a lookup relationship (the object referred to by the lookup).

This is setup on the page layout by adding the Related list to the existing related lists.